# JavaScript is incorrectly trying to read path as a number - outputs NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a hover function in Utilities namespace to return translated English word on mouseover:

```
hoverText : function () {
    $("#npc_dialog").lettering('words'); //split dialog into spans for hover

    //Provide translation on hover for Player Dialog
    $("#npc_dialog span").on("mouseover", function() {
        var word = $(this).text();
        $("#currentWord").text(Vocab.parseHoveredText(word, false));
        playSound(Vocab.parseHoveredText(word, true));
    })
}
```

This calls `Vocab.parseHoveredText()` to loop through vocab object and return either the translated word, or an audio path which will sound out the word.

Originally I had `this.path+this.sbj+file.mp3` if I need to dynamically change paths later. The sound plays when I manually type the path in (in the case of 'wo'), but if I use the `this.path+...` console outputs `NaNNi_You.mp3`. Why is it trying to read it as a number when the path is NOT a number?

I've already verified the `this.path` and `this.sbj` paths are working in the console.log below.

```
//namespace
var Vocab = {

path : 'recordings/',
sbj : 'subjects/',
//more stuff

vocab : 
    {
        Subjects :
        {   
            'wǒ'    : ['I/Me',              'recordings/subjects/Wo_I.mp3'],
            'nǐ'    : ['You',               this.path+this.sbj+'Ni_You.mp3'],
            //more stuff
```

My parseHoveredText function:

```
parseHoveredText : function (word, audio) {
        for (obj in this.vocab) {
            if(this.vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()]) { 
                if(audio) {
                    //Hover over 'wǒ': outputs: "path: recordings/subjects/Wo_I.mp3"
                    console.log("path: " + this.path+this.sbj+'Wo_I.mp3');

                    //Hover over 'wǒ': outputs: "log: recordings/subjects/Wo_I.mp3"
                    //Hover over 'nǐ': outputs: "log: NaNNi_You.mp3"
                    console.log("log: " + this.vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][1]);
                    return this.vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][1];

                }
                return this.vocab[obj][word.toLowerCase()][0];
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown the entire code, it's not possible to say precisely, but when `Vocab` is defined, it is in some scope, possibly/probably the global scope. In any case, `this` is equal to that scope. So when your code says `this.path+this.sbj` JavaScript expects to find `path` and `sbj` in that scope, not as properties of the object. Since they aren't defined in that scope, `undefined + undefined` is `NaN`.

Comment: Good point. But when I console.log `this.path+this.sbj` it's outputting the correct path in console as a string. Correct, var Vocab is defined in global scope, and path, sbj, n, v are properties of Vocab. Would I be better to put them as `Vocab.path+Vocab.adj...`?

Comment: only when you console.log `this.path...` from within a function that's called with the `Vocab` object as its scope.

Comment: And, no, you can't use `Vocab` within the `Vocab` object because it is undefined.

Comment: Best suggestion is to spend 10-15 minutes reading up on JavaScript scope. Dr. Google knows lots of resources.